# Hive query to return result from table when the condition doesn't meet

Tags: hive

I am looking for hive query which returns me all results only if the DataSet doesn't have subject : History in it.. Please note the dataset will change every time

DataSet :

[image]
DataSet :

[image]

So first DataSet above has record with Subject : History , so 0 records should be returned and  second dataset doesn't have subject : history so in this case all 4 records should be returned

Answer (score 0):

Analytic function will return the same history_exists flag for all and every row:

```
select id, name, age, subject, score
from
(
 select t.*, max(case when t,subject='History' then true else false end) over() as history_exists --the same value for all dataset
  from your_table t
)s
where NOT history_exists;
```